# jQuery .test returns false with regular expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Here's a simple code that test input value if it does exist on regular expression. The main problem is that it always returns to false though the inputted value should return to true with regex.

HTML

```
<input id="user" type="text" />
```

jQuery

```
$("#user").on("input propertychange",function(){

    var user = $(this).val();
    var pattern = /[^a-zA-Z 0-9 . -]/g;
    var clean_user = user.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9 . -]+/g, '');

    // Filter text box
    $("#user").val(clean_user);
    var fresh_user_value = $("#user").val(clean_user);

    if(pattern.test(fresh_user_value) == true){
        alert("Working!");
    }
});
```

Comment: Why are you cleaning that way?

Comment: @ArunPJohny: The if condition returns to false whenever I try it.

Comment: The return value of `.val()` used as a setter is either `undefined` or it returns `$('#user')` itself.

Comment: I'll check the code again, thanks for the reply everyone. (y)

Answer (score 1):

Change :

```
if(pattern.test(fresh_user_value) === true)
```

To:

```
if(pattern.test(clean_user))
```

When you declare `fresh_user_value`, you do this:

```
var fresh_user_value = $("#user").val(clean_user);
```

The value returned from that isn't the string, it's the jQuery object.

You could also do:

```
var fresh_user_value = $("#user").val();
```

As mentioned in another answer, but it's redundant.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5w78B/4/)

[jQuery docs for `.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2)

Note: For your own sake, avoid using `alert` for this kind of thing (or any kind of thing).

Comment: Hi, mosho! thanks for the reply. I just used the alert for sample purposes. thanks again, I'll try your solution:)

Answer (score 1):

You can just apply the replacement like so:

```
$(this).val(function(_, value) {
    return value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9 . -]+/g, '');
});
```

Since you're using the same expression to test as well as replace, it's logical that after the matching characters have been removed from the string that it will pass the test.

Comment: Hi! thanks for this.. I'll try this and the other given solutions. Thanks again! (y)

Answer (score 0):

You're setting and not getting the value here:

```
var fresh_user_value = $("#user").val(clean_user);
```

Change to:

```
var fresh_user_value = $("#user").val();
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply. I tried changing it to $("#user").val(); but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Note: The flags argument does not work in v8 Core (Chrome and NodeJs). A string specifying a combination of regular expression flags. The use of the flags parameter in the String.replace method is non-standard. Instead of using this parameter, use a RegExp object with the corresponding flags. The value of this parameter if it is used should be a string consisting of one or more of the following characters to affect the operation as describe

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

`user.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9 . -]+/g, '');`

If you are using chrome, then flags (`g`) will not work.

Your other problem is the logic at this point:

```
$("#user").val(clean_user);
var fresh_user_value = $("#user").val(clean_user);
```

In `fresh_user_value`, to get the value of the `#user` element, all you would need to do is this:

```
$("#user").val();
```

No need to pass an argument to `val()`, if you just need the current value. Passing an argument will change the element's value property.

Comment: Hi! thanks for the reply. I'll surely try your solution. thanks again (y)